# Validation Dynamically created Field using Formik Yup

Tags: formik, yup

I need to validate Dynamically created fields with formik or yup .I have seen this validation done by in jquery validatioh [here](http://thewebfosters.com/validate-dynamically-generated-input-fields-jquery-validation-plugin/)

[image: like this] to this [image: to this]

My code in here
https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-haze-47k73?file=/src/demo.js

How do i achieve this using formik and yup

Comment: Can you explain what you do to create fields dynamically? `FieldArray` or what ? Can you show minimum code for it?

Comment: Please wait i will update

Comment: I have updated my code link .I'm working on your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you using `formik` `FieldArray`. You can check it's fields with `yup`:

```
firends: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
       name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
       email: Yup.string()
                .email("Invalid email")
                .required('Email is required'),
    })
),
```

And your `FieldArray` will be:

```
<FieldArray                                                          
 name="firends"
 render={(arrayHelpers) => {
  {values.firends && values.firends.length > 0 ? (
     values.firends.map((friend, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <Field
         className="form-control"
         name={`friends.${index}.name`}
         placeholder="name"
         type="text"
      />
        {errors &&
         errors.friends &&
         errors.friends[index] &&
         errors.friends[index].name &&
           (touched &&
            touched.friends &&
            touched.friends[index] &&
            touched.friends[index].name) && (
              <div className="field-error">
                {errors.friends[index].name}
              </div>
      )}
     <Field
         className="form-control"
         name={`friends.${index}.email`}
         placeholder="email"
         type="text"
      />
        {errors &&
         errors.friends &&
         errors.friends[index] &&
         errors.friends[index].email &&
           (touched &&
            touched.friends &&
            touched.friends[index] &&
            touched.friends[index].email) && (
              <div className="field-error">
                {errors.friends[index].email}
              </div>
      )}
  </div>
  ))
 }}
```

You can find fully ready code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fieldarray-with-yup-validation-f27q3?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Hi validation worked but I'm losing focus when add new fields ,Any way to give focus on empty field on submit

Comment: That CodeSandbox doesn't work. It says TypeError.